# Calendar Heat Map show image when hover

Tags: javascript, heatmap

http://cal-heatmap.com/v2/
I want to show some custom message when user click on any particular sub Domain in cal-heat map i read all document but not able to find how to do that if any one can help me here save my time a lot. similar i found similar example in GitHub contributor calender graph.

I used below method but it is accept only time and value.

http://cal-heatmap.com/#onClick

```
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({
    itemSelector: "#onClick-a",
    domain: "day",
    range: 5, data: "datas-years.json",
    start: new Date(2000, 0),
    onClick: function(date, nb) {
        $("#onClick-placeholder").html("You just clicked <br/>on <b>" +
            date + "</b> <br/>with <b>" +
            (nb === null ? "unknown" : nb) + "</b> items"
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `nb === null` or `nb === undefined`? I would assume `undefined`